# How to make x=2a+3b in 4 instructions limit using ONLY mov,add,sub,neg?

Tags: assembly, addition, x86-16, mov

Let's say x is a register which its value isn't known.
I have to make `x=2a+3b` where `a` and `b` have unknown values.

I can use the 8086 asm instructions `mov`, `add`, `sub`, `neg` only.
The use of the `mul` instruction isn't allowed, and also there is a limit of 4 instructions only.

Is it even possible?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Rewrite your expression:

```
2a + 3b = 2(a + b) + b = (a + b) + (a + b) + b
```

Note that you only need to compute the value of `(a + b)` once.

Comment: just for reference this is common sub-expression elimination combined with algebraic reduction (reduction followed by CSE), just incase the OP wants to do further research.

Comment: Thank you, now I figured it out.